# Why does my HTTP response using Python Sockets fail?

Tags: python, http, sockets, webserver, httpresponse

Code:

```
from socket import *
sP = 14000
servSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
servSock.bind(('',sP))
servSock.listen(1)

while 1:
  connSock, addr = servSock.accept()
  connSock.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/html\nConnection:close\n<html>...</html>')
connSock.close()
```

When I go to the browser and type in localhost:14000, I get an error 101- ERR_CONNECTION_RESET The connection was reset? Not sure why! What am I doing wrong

Comment: You need a \n on an empty line before the response body. So ...Connection:close\n\n<html>...

Comment: Change all `'\n'` to `'\r\n'`, and have an empty line after the header. And read the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several bugs, some more severe than others ... as @IanWetherbee already noted, you need an empty line before the body.  You also should send \r\n not just \n.  You should use `sendall` to avoid short sends.  Last, you need to close the connection once you're done sending.

Here's a slightly modified version of the above:

```
from socket import *
sP = 14000
servSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
servSock.bind(('',sP))
servSock.listen(1)

while 1:
  connSock, addr = servSock.accept()
  connSock.sendall('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:text/html\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n<html><head>foo</head></html>\r\n')
  connSock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code, I have similar errors and am unsure on their origins too.  However, rather than rolling your own HTTP server, have you considered a built in one?  Check out the sample below.  This can also support POST as well (have to add the do_POST method).

**Simple HTTP Server**

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class customHTTPServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write('<HTML><body>Hello World!</body></HTML>')
                return 

def main():
        try:
                server = HTTPServer(('',14000),customHTTPServer)
                print 'server started at port 14000'
                server.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                server.socket.close() 

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```